# Youtube video is not loaded in webview in android

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube

I want to display youtube URL in a web view. But it is not loading into the web view.

Here is my code.

```
     WebView web_view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    web_view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    web_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    web_view.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    web_view.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    web_view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    web_view.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8n16rns-iM");
```

the video is not loaded into the web view.It is showing error:
[INFO: CONSOLE(16)] "The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported.", source: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=s8n16rns-iM

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 String frameVideo = "<html><body>Video From YouTube<br><iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ue80QwXMRHg&app=desktop\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

WebView displayYoutubeVideo = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mWebView);
displayYoutubeVideo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }
});
WebSettings webSettings = displayYoutubeVideo.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
displayYoutubeVideo.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: how can i get frameVideo for this video url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ue80QwXMRHg&app=desktop

Answer (score 0):

To get a html frame for a particular video, use this function with a Video Id,

```
public String getHtmlfromVideoId(String videoId) {
        String html = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" " + "style=\"border: 0; width: 100%; height: 96%;"
                + "padding:0px; margin:0px\" " + "id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" "
                + "src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoId
                + "?&theme=dark&autohide=2&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1\fs=0\" frameborder=\"0\" "
                + "allowfullscreen autobuffer " + "controls onclick=\"this.play()\">\n" + "</iframe>\n";
        return html;
    }
```

Video Id usually comes after the **v** parameter of the youtube url. For example, the Video Id of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8n16rns-iM&app=desktop is **s8n16rns-iM**

Once you get the html frame, load it directly in the WebView,

```
webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I want to show the total youtube with that Url in webview